# MomentJS Parsing Unix Timestamp Sent Through GET Request Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, date, get, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I have an array of 2 strings, both of which are in Unix time.

```
[1484930449590,1548002449590]
```

Converting these back into human readable time gives me today's date and the date 2 years ago.

However, when I parse both of these timestamps with MomentJS:

```
const start = moment(timeRange[0])
const end = moment(timeRange[1])
```

I receive the following values:

```
moment("2001-01-01T00:00:00.000")
moment("2001-04-01T00:00:00.000")
```

For some reason, momentJS converts both of the timestamps to the year 2001, even though the years should be 2019 and 2017.

Parsing the strings first does not make things better:

```
const start = moment(parseInt(timeRange[0]))
const end = moment(parseInt(timeRange[1]))
```

Now `start` and `end` are:

```
moment("1969-12-31T19:00:00.001")
moment("1969-12-31T19:00:00.004")
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

I tried the following solution:

```
console.log(timeRange)
const start = moment(parseInt(timeRange[0]) / 1000)
console.log(start)
const end = moment(parseInt(timeRange[1]) / 1000)
console.log(end)
```

but nothing changed:

```
1484931697215,1548003697215
moment("1969-12-31T19:00:00.000")
moment("1969-12-31T19:00:00.000")
```

Update:

The issue is that I was wrong about `timeRange` being an array. Rather, it was actually a string. This happened because on the client-side `timeRange` was an array, but when it got sent as a GET request to the server and retrieved with `const timeRange = req.query.timeRange`, it got converted to a string.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pv3juaqn/ `parseInt` works for me

Comment: @apokryfos something fishy is going on, maybe the issue is related to the fact that I'm receiving the `timeRange` array as an URL query parameter in a GET request. I tested your fiddle, and it worked fine on my computer. I'll put an update in my post.

Comment: Could you post how you are retrieving `timeRange` or post a `var_dump($timeRange)`?

Comment: @Laurens I figured out the issue, it turns out `timeRange` was a sting because i did `const timeRange = req.query.timeRange` and assumed `timeRange` would be an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was wrong about `timeRange` being an array. Rather, it was actually a string. This happened because on the client-side `timeRange` was an array, but when it got sent as part of a GET request to the server and retrieved with const `timeRange = req.query.timeRange`, it got converted to a string.

The solution was to reconvert the `timeRange` back into an array:

```
const times = req.query.timeRange.split(",")
const startDate = moment(parseInt(times[0]))
const endDate = moment(parseInt(times[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp is in milliseconds, not in seconds. Try dividing by 1000 first:

```
const start = moment(parseInt(timeRange[0]/1000))
const end = moment(parseInt(timeRange[1]/1000))
```

That should give you the correct date

Comment: The Moment documentation says that if the timestamp is in milliseconds it can be directly passed into the constructor, like so: `moment(Number);` https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/. I tried your solution anyway, but nothing changed.

Comment: You are right. Seems to work perfectly fine with milliseconds: http://jsfiddle.net/3kvsq2dw/